# "Prompted by" the oil crises of the 1970s

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **Prompted by** the oil crises of the 1970s, a wind-power industry flourished briefly in the United States. But then world oil prices dropped, and funding for research into renewable energy was cut. [Wind Power in the US](http://www.examenglish.com/IELTS/IELTS_reading_2.htm)

What is the *Prompted by* mean? is it mean "*After* the oil crises of the 1970s" , "*affected by* the oil crises of the 1970s"? or maybe *because of*?

**Note:** I couldn't match the meanings in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prompt?q=prompted) with the above context.

Comment: It's the very first definition there: *to make something happen*.  A wind-power industry flourished in the United States, and the oil crises of the 1970s *made it happen*.

Comment: "to make something happen". You can replace it with **pushed**. "Pushed by the oil crises of the 1970s.."

Comment: @CowperKettle : jinx!  :^)

Comment: I suggest using the Cambridge [Learner's Dictionary entry](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/prompt_1?q=prompted), or another learner's dictionary like  [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prompt_1) or [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prompt_2). General purpose dictionaries are aimed at native speakers.

Comment: The essence of the usage here is **triggered by**.  Investment in and development of a wind-power industry was triggered by the oil crisis.  That industry flourished briefly until oil prices dropped, and funding for research into renewable energy was cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cambridge Dictionary uses the verb **make** rather loosely in its definition.

When something "prompts" action, the "something" in question is usually a set of circumstances that provide sufficient motivation for someone to take action.

> The car's third breakdown in as many weeks prompted me to buy a new
>   one.
>
> Prompted by the demand for smaller cars that arose during the oil crisis of the 1970s, American car makers began offering vehicles with smaller engines and better fuel-efficiency.
>
> You stood up in the middle of the speech and yelled "The mackerel likes frying!" What on earth prompted you to do that?

The sentence in your example is a little odd: something cannot be *prompted* to *flourish*:

> **Sustained** by memories of the oil crisis of the 1970s, a wind-power
>   industry flourished briefly in the United States.